# Django - como hacer consultas en varias tablas (join)?

Tags: django

Muy buenos días. Estoy pasando un proyecto de Codeigniter a Django y he tenido problemas para entender los querys en varias tablas, y con varios parámetros. El modelo de datos que tengo es el siguiente:

```
class Municipios(models.Model):
    codmunicipio        = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)  
    coddepartamento     = models.ForeignKey(Departamentos, on_delete =  models.PROTECT, db_column = 'coddepartamento')  
    nombre              = models.CharField(max_length = 50)

class Telefonos(models.Model):  
    id                  = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)  
    codmunicipio        = models.ForeignKey(Municipios, on_delete = models.PROTECT, db_column = 'codmunicipio')  
    nombre              = models.CharField(max_length = 250)  
    telefono            = models.BigIntegerField(default = 0)  
    telefono2           = models.BigIntegerField(default = 0)  
    celular             = models.BigIntegerField(default = 0)  
    celular2            = models.BigIntegerField(default = 0)  
    email               = models.EmailField(max_length = 60, default = '')
```

Y quiero hacer una consulta como esta, donde se utilice el operador "o" según coincida varios campos con comparacion string:

```
select t.telefono,t.celular, t.nombre, m.nombre as municipio  
from telefonos as t, municipios as m 
where t.codmunicipio= m.codmunicipio and (t.telefono like '%$stelefono%' or t.celular like '%$stelefono%' )  
union all select t.telefono,t.celular, t.nombre, m.nombre as municipio  
from telefonos as t, municipios as m 
where t.codmunicipio= m.codmunicipio and (t.telefono like concat('%',right('$stelefono',7)) or t.celular like concat('%',right('$stelefono',7))  ) 
limit 30 offset $registro
```

La pregunta va orientada, a cómo hacer una consulta con varias tablas, donde hay un join. EN Django es facil de hacer consultas de una tabla, pero tengo la dificultad cuando son varias

Answer (score 1):

Si la duda viene por el uso del operador `or`. Puedes usar la clase [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

Telefonos.objects.filter(Q(telefono=variable_telefono) | Q(celular=variabke_telefono))
```

Los JOIN los ejecuta el ORM mediante las condiciones que realizas usando la el campo que es un FK o usando la notacion [`__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships):

```
Telefonos.objects.filter(codmunicipio__nombre='nombre_de_un_municipio')
```

Esto hará un JOIN con el modelo (tabla) `Municipio` usando como referencia el campo `nombre`

Comment: La duda va más enfocada a como usar el ORM para hacer consultas en varias tablas.

Comment: @JairoMarin Edité la respuesta